# Plot training error performance vs. number of epochs as a function of learning rate η

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

```
class LinearRegressionUsingGD:

    def __init__(self, n_iterations=1000):
        self.n_iterations = n_iterations

    def fit(self, x, y, lrate):
        self.cost_ = []
        self.w_ = np.zeros((x.shape[1], 1))
        m = x.shape[0]

        for _ in range(self.n_iterations):
            y_pred = np.dot(x, self.w_)
            residuals = y_pred - y
            gradient_vector = np.dot(x.T, residuals)
            self.w_ -= (lrate / m) * gradient_vector
            cost = np.sum((residuals ** 2)) / (2 * m)
            self.cost_.append(cost)
        return self.w_, self.cost_

        pyplot.plot(self.cost_, lrate, label='train')
        pyplot.title('lrate='+str(lrate), pad=-50)


lr = LinearRegressionUsingGD()

learning_rates = [1E-6, 1E-5, 1E-4, 1E-3, 1E-2, 1E-1]

for i in range(len(learning_rates)):
  # determine the plot number
  plot_no = 420 + (i+1)
  pyplot.subplot(plot_no)
  # fit model and plot learning curves for a learning rate
  lr.fit(X_train, y_train, learning_rates[i])

pyplot.show()
```

I am running the above code in my Jupyter notebook and it's just giving me 6 blank graphs.

I want to plot training error performance vs. number of epochs as a function of learning rate  η.

Can someone please correct the code and tell me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will encounter some other issues, i.e., you are plotting a single value `lrate` a thousand times, but your main problem is resolved by getting rid of `return self.w_, self.cost_`. It is not used in your code and will exit the function before the plots are made. A simplified working example would be:

```py
import numpy as np
import pylab as pyplot

class LinearRegressionUsingGD:

    def __init__(self, n_iterations=1000):
        self.n_iterations = n_iterations

    def fit(self, lrate):
        self.cost_ = []

        for _ in range(self.n_iterations):
            self.cost_.append(np.random.random())

        pyplot.plot(self.cost_, [lrate]*1000, label='train')
        pyplot.title('lrate='+str(lrate), pad=-50)


lr = LinearRegressionUsingGD()
learning_rates = [1E-6, 1E-5, 1E-4, 1E-3, 1E-2, 1E-1]

for i in range(len(learning_rates)):
  plot_no = 420 + (i+1)
  pyplot.subplot(plot_no)
  lr.fit(learning_rates[i])

pyplot.show()
```